# Do you need an Google account to use Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Background: Is it possible to have user without an google account to use **google bigquery web UI** to query your data?

I know you can set quota based on google group and add people that does not have a google account in there. I am thinking since this is possible, there might be a way to let user use BigQuery without an google account.

Trying to use the quota function with Google BigQuery web UI. I am not sure if they are able to access Google BigQuery web UI without an Google Account even.

Comment: _there might be a way to let user use BigQuery without an google account._ It's possible, without BQ Web UI, without user accounts, with a service account and with quota control - see [this](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-bigquery) project. I'm the author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no. Our web UI requires sign in with a Google account.

Comment: I would guess this apply for OAuth 2 authentication as well, when using an web application.